# Negation of Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a Criteria that is a set of several Restrictions.
The execution of the query with this criteria returns a set of data . 
Then I have to collect all data except the data returned by the first query.

Is there a method to achieve this starting from the Criteria already used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build from the individual `Criterion` objects using `Restrictions.not` and remembering that not (*A* and *B*) = not *A* or not *B*.